# Finding Debt to Equity ratio

Tags: united-states, stocks, investing

I was looking at Bank of America's 10-Q and I wanted to find the D/E ratio by doing total liabilities over stockholder's equity

[image]

But this looked super odd because the D/E ratio would be 8.88 which I never even heard of it going there. I then googled historical D/E ratios for BAC but it never has hit anywhere close to 8.88 so I'm probably doing this wrong any suggestions how to fix my error?

[Link to Edgar SEC for BAC 10-Q](https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/19617/000001961720000299/corpq12020.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you search for BAC debt to equity ratio most results aren't using total liabilities but just total long term debt.

From [Zacks](https://www.zacks.com/stock/chart/BAC/fundamental/debt-equity-ratio-quarterly):
[image: Zacks]

And Macrotrends snippet from Google results:

[image: Macrotrends]

While D/E Ratio is simply defined as Total Liabilities over Total Shareholders Equity, it's frequently adjusted to be more useful.